# Elastic search is returning objects that have been deleted

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, web-deployment

Just like title says. For some reason, on my website, if a guild is created then deleted, it will still show up in the search results but navigating to the page, or querying by guild ID shows that the object doesn't exist.

What would cause this?

Answer (score 3):

A document is marked for deletion, not actually physically removed, at least not immediately. More about this behavior here: [Lucene's Handling of Deleted Documents](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents). It is possible to force a refresh to make the deletion reflect search results on a per document basis: [?refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html). Alternatively you could call a refresh on the index by `POST <index>/_refresh` (as mentioned here: [Refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html)) which makes all operations since last refresh available for search immediately as well.